# Multiplicative group of a field (not necessarily finite)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be any field, is $F^{\times}=F\setminus\{0\}$ always true? I know this is true for finite fields. What about infinite fields?

Comment: How do you define $F^{\times}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is always true, typically by definition. It is common, for fields $F$, to define
$$
F^\times := F \setminus \{0\}
$$
More broadly, for rings $R$, one can define
$$\begin{align*}
R^\times &:= \{ r \in R \mid \text{$r$ a unit in $R$} \} \\
R_{\ne 0} &:= R \setminus \{0\}
\end{align*}$$
These are generally not equal, but if $R$ is a field, then $R_{\ne 0} = R^\times$. That is to say, $R^\times$ is the set of invertible elements, and when $R$ is a field, then all nonzero elements are invertible.

Comment: Your $R_{\ne 0} $ is more commonly denoted $R^*$.

Comment: @lhf May I ask, where did you see such notation? I always seen $R^{\times}$ or $R^*$ as notations for the invertible elements of $R$. Not sure why one would even give a special notation to the nonzero elements of a ring. This set is usually not that important.

Comment: I've seen my algebra professor last semester use $R_{\ne 0}$, and I know I've seen it in *some* algebra textbook or another though I'm not sure which.

Comment: The common notation for the group of units of a ring is $R^{\times}$. For a field $R$ of course $R^{\times}=R\setminus 0$. Sometimes $U(n)$ is used, for the ring $R=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. A notation $R_{\neq 0}$ is unnecessarily clumsy. For the field of real numbers there are notations like $\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$, or $\Bbb R^+$, or $\Bbb R_{+}$ in all variations.